# What method of compression should I use to pre-compress html snapshots?

Tags: html, apache

I've got millions of html files, snapshots of my dynamic webapp for serving to search engines (the whole _escaped_fragment_ malarky - it takes 1.5s to generate these snapshots so I'm caching them).  I'd like to pre-compress these files and serve them through Apache (via PHP which will generate a new snapshot if one doesn't exist) without decompressing them and then having mod_deflate recompress them.

What method of compression should I use to pre-compress these html snapshots ready for pushing through php/Apache?